# Read integers from a text file and sort them into another text file and a binary file

Tags: c, sorting, io

*I forgot to include the programming language (It should be in the C language).*

I need help in doing this program. Sample code will be greatly appreciated.

The program reads a file containing:

a. the number of integers to be sorted, followed by 
 b. the integers to be sorted (one integer per line) (must be the same with the indicated number of integers).

It will then be sorted out in another text file and a binary file from lowest to highest.

Other specs:

1. Use dynamic memory allocation
2. The format in the terminal should be:

   ```
   ./program.out  original-file.txt  output-file.txt  output-file.bin
   ```

where `program.out` is the program itself, `original-file.txt` is the text file which contains the number of integers to be sorted and the unsorted integers and the `output-file.txt` and `output-file.bin` contains the sorted integers.

Error checking:

1. check if malloc() was returned successfully

the original file will look like:

```
3 #number of integers to be sorted
3 #the integers-separated by new line
2
1
```

the output file:

```
3
1
2
3
```

Thank you very much in advance :) God Bless!

Comment: so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: This looks to me like a coursework assignment.  Is it?

Comment: What's `output-file.bin`?  Integers in binary format (using `Int` type)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct tree {
  int num, cnt;
  struct tree *left, *right;
};
struct tree *add(struct tree *t, int val) {
  if (!t) {
    if (!(t = malloc(sizeof(struct tree))))
      perror("Not enough memory"), exit(-1);
    memset(t, 0, sizeof(struct tree));
    t->num = val;
    ++t->cnt;
    return t;
  }
  if (val < t->num)
    t->left = add(t->left, val);
  else if (val > t->num)
    t->right = add(t->right, val);
  else
    ++t->cnt;
  return t;
}
int walk(struct tree *t, int (*f)(struct tree *, void*), void *data) {
  int rc;
  if (!t)
    return 0;
  rc = walk(t->left, f, data);
  rc += f(t, data);
  rc += walk(t->right, f, data);
  return rc;
}
struct tree *clean(struct tree *t) {
  if (!t)
    return NULL;
  t->left = clean(t->left);
  t->right = clean(t->right);
  free(t);
  return NULL;
}
int save(struct tree *t, void *data) {
  int i, rc = 0;
  FILE *fp = (FILE *) data;
  for (i = 0; i < t->cnt; ++i)
    rc += (fprintf(fp, "%d\n", t->num) < 0);
  return rc;
}
int saveb(struct tree *t, void *data) {
  int i, rc = 0;
  FILE *fp = (FILE *) data;
  for (i = 0; i < t->cnt; ++i)
    rc += (fwrite((void *) &t->num, sizeof t->num, 1, fp) != 1);
  return rc;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int rc = 0;
  struct tree *t = NULL;
  char buff[0x200];
  FILE *fin, *fout, *foutb;
  if (argc < 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s SRCFILE OUTFILE.TXT OUTFILE.BIN\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
  }
  if (!((fin = fopen(argv[1], "r")) && (fout = fopen(argv[2], "w"))
        && (foutb = fopen(argv[3], "wb")))) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(-1);
  }
  while (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fin))
    t = add(t, atoi(buff));
  rc += walk(t, save, (void *) fout);
  rc += walk(t, saveb, (void *) foutb);
  t = clean(t);
  fclose(fin);
  fclose(fout);
  fclose(foutb);
  return rc;
}
```

Just noticed the "number of integers in first string of a file" spec; I think your teacher ment you'd put them into array and sort it; but anyway do it yourself :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
  return *(int*)a > *(int*)b ? 1 : (*(int*)a < *(int*)b ? -1 : 0);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char buff[0x200];
  FILE *fin, *fout, *foutb;
  int i, *arr, sz = 0, rc = 0;
  if (argc < 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s SRCFILE OUTFILE.TXT OUTFILE.BIN\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
  }
  if (!((fin = fopen(argv[1], "r")) && (fout = fopen(argv[2], "w"))
        && (foutb = fopen(argv[3], "wb")))) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(-1);
  }
  if (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fin)) {
    sz = atoi(buff);
    if (!(arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * sz)))
      perror("Not enough memory"), exit(-1);
    for (i = 0; i < sz && fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fin); ++i)
      arr[i] = atoi(buff);
  }
  qsort(arr, sz, sizeof(int), cmp);
  for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    rc += (fprintf(fout, "%d\n", arr[i]) < 0);
  for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    rc += (fwrite((void *) &arr[i], sizeof(int), 1, foutb) != 1);
  fclose(fin);
  fclose(fout);
  fclose(foutb);
  return rc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I now have an idea on what to do. :) God Bless!

Comment: Idea? :) All you need to do is copypaste second code and compile it :) Hope you'll have some time to actually read and understand it.

Comment: As much as I wanted to copy and paste, I want to create my own code :)) I tried running the program but the number of integers to be sorted (which is number 3 in the example above) wasn't written on the output files, what should I do to make that appear on the output files?

Comment: @John Well, you should write it to output file. As you may noticed, it's stored in the `sz` variable.

Comment: Oh I see, Thank you very much! I'll just ask some questions again if I encounter some problems in my code, if you don't mind. Thanks again!

Comment: What does the char buff[0x200] do? Should it be always [0x200]

Comment: It's just a buffer size (512 bytes). You can change this value according your needs. Just choose large enough value to place the largest string you'll have in your input.

Comment: Thank you! Just last question, what does this code do?  if (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fin)) {
    sz = atoi(buff);

Comment: `fgets()` function reads string of maximum `sizeof buff` bytes from file handler `fin` to array `buff`. It returns pointer to `buff` on success or `NULL` otherwise. `atoi` function converts null-terminated string to integer. `sizeof` operator calculates size of variable at compile-time. More correct code would be `sizeof buff * sizeof buff[0]`: capacity of array multiplied by size of each element but since our array's elements have type of `char` and it's guaranteed that `sizeof(char) == 1` we can skip this part.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some sample codes. If you google for these function names, and if you stayed awake in class, I'm sure you'll do fine. You'll probably need to:

- open a file:

  `FILE* inFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");`
- read a single value from the input

  `int numConverted = fscanf(inFile, "%d", &value);`
- allocate some memory:

  `int *pInts = malloc(n * sizeof(int));`
- sort the array

  `// The parameters are tricky! Check your class notes or text book`
  `qsort(...)`
- write a single value out as text

  `fprintf(outFile, "%d\n", i);`
- write a single value out as binary:

  `fwrite( &i, sizeof i, 1, outBinFile);`